# Where can I ask questions about document formatting and design?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

**Is there a site where I can ask about formatting and design decisions for creating standardized documentation and templates?**

Specifically, I'm looking to ask how different bullet levels should be handled when mixing numbered and bulleted lists.

Example: In a document, bullets for level 1 and sub-bullets for level 2 are styled as `•` and `o` respectively. When making sub-bullets for a numbered list, should those sub-bullets use the styling for level 1 bullets, or level 2 sub-bullets?

[image: Comparison of mixed bullet styles]

---

I've considered a few different sites:

- [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/)

  - (**+**) Deals with subjective user experience issues.
  - (**+**) Template will be utilized by normal users.
  - (**-**) Focused on program design, rather than document design.
- [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)

  - (**+**) Fitting for visual design questions.
  - (**-**) Focused on questions relating to image design.
  - (**-**) More appropriate for issues with image editing software.
- Super User

  - (**+**) Relates to formatting Microsoft Word documents.
  - (**-**) Suited for directly answerable technical questions.
  - (**-**) Does not allow opinion-based questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're mistaken that Graphic Design is focused only on images and image-editing software. We most certainly welcome [typography](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typography) questions and non-software related questions (as well as software other than typical design software; e.g. [Microsoft Office](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office)).

Some vaguely similar questions (the first few I found... I'm not using these as examples of good questions, just to show that they are on-topic) for reference:

- [Formatting different telephone numbers](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/76421/52050)
- [Is it good practice to add additional space before a punctuation mark after emphazised text?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/16252/52050)
- [Principles of Typography for different languages](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/13697/52050)
- [Typography: treatment of brand names in scientific publication](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/92634/52050)

Your question could probably do with some more work; give some more context, do some research etc., but it is on-topic.

Also, If your question is asking in relation to an existing design you're working on, please have a look at the guidelines for critique questions:

- [What are the guidelines for asking for a critique of my work?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/681/52050)

Answer (score 3):

Those questions are on-topic on [Writers](https://writers.stackexchange.com/).  Here are some similar questions:

[Writing a programming book: how to present directory structures](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/6078/writing-a-programming-book-how-to-present-directory-structures), [When should I use punctuation with bullets?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/2404/when-should-i-use-punctuation-with-bullets), and 197 others in the [formatting](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formatting) tag.

[Which words should not be capitalized in Title Case?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/4621/which-words-should-not-be-capitalized-in-title-case), [Dashes vs. Commas vs. parentheses?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/1409/dashes-vs-commas-vs-parentheses), and 716 other in the [style](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style) tag.

[Good Outlining Solutions For OSX?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/1804/good-outlining-solutions-for-osx), [Demo data in screenshots! What are the best practice?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/8185/demo-data-in-screenshots-what-are-the-best-practice), [Starting a sentence with the name of a program or command-line tool: capitalization?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/23419/starting-a-sentence-with-the-name-of-a-program-or-command-line-tool-capitalizat), and 244 others in the [technical-writing](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-writing) tag.

Questions about specialized tools such as Scrivener, MadCap Flare, and Doxygen are also on-topic.  (But not general-purpose tools like Microsoft Office.)